# How to evaluate if a particular value exists in every single key in a dictionary that has arrays as values on Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

Let's say I have the following dictionary in a Python program:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['None', 'Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 'Cuerpo': ['None', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['None', 'Oceano.png'], 'Ojos': ['None', 'Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

How can I verify that the element `'None'` exists in every single key from the dictionary above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all(['None' in v for k, v in the_dictionary_list.items()])`

This loops through the dictionary key value pairs and returns a `True` or `False` if `'None'` is in the value. And then `all` checks if they are all true if one is false it will return `False` if all are `True` it returns true